# org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type Account to type AllAccount

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using SpringBoot and JPA to call db, 
I am getting exception as

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [com.xxx.central.model.Account] to type
>   [com.xxx.central.model.AllAccount]

Below is my code

**Account.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
```

**AllAccount.java**

```
@Entity(name="allAccounts")
@Table(name = "account")
public class AllAccount implements Serializable {
```

**AccountRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = Account.class, idClass = Integer.class)
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer> 
{

public List<AllAccount> 
findByIsActiveAndClientNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrderByAccountCreatedDesc(
        Boolean active, String clientNameSearchString);
}
```

When i am calling above repository from my service class i getting exception.
Where i am going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: what do you have in `AllAccount` class? If its just a list of `Account` then you can try to rather return list of `Account` from the repository class instead of `AllAccount`

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer>
```

This line makes your Repository class only return types of object `Account`.

That's why when you call

```
public List<AllAccount> 
findByIsActiveAndClientNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrderByAccountCreatedDesc
```

it tries to covert from type `Account` to `AllAccount` which it can't and hence the exception.

Either you create a different repository class for `AllAccount` or change this one to return `AllAccount` by changing to

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<AllAccount, Integer>
```

Comment: Thank for giving your precious time. Above solution worked for me. I created new repository class rather changing Account.                                                                                                                         Thank a lot.